# When to check if user is logged in?

Tags: ios, authentication, nsurlconnection

So I'm working on an app that communicates with a web server. The app has a login page, after which the main contents are revealed(when logged in).
My question is when should I check to see if the user is logged in when the app is launched?
Currently, I'm storing the cookies, and making a request at the start of the app, but the request has a slight delay. This causes the login screen to be visible for a second and then (when the response is received) the view segues to the content view. The problem is that if logged in, the user shouldn't have to see/ wait for the login view at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a call back after you are logged in. And I am also assuming that each user has a unique `userID`. When the user logs in you will have a callback method where you are presenting the home page. Before you present, save the userID in your `NSUserDefaults` something like,

```
//Assume that an instance of NSDictionary called responseDictionary has the user_id
NSString *userID = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:userID forKey:@"user_id"];
```

Now, the next time when the user launches your application, in your `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method of the `AppDelegate.m` file, set the `rootViewController` aptly. Here is an example.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIViewController *rootViewController;
if([defaults objectForKey:@"user_id"]] != nil) {
   rootViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}
else {
   rootViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}
[self.window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

Make sure to remove the `userID` object from defaults when you are adding the logout functionality, like so:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I decided to load the views this way, so that the user doesn't need to wait, but also keep the call back in case the session has been invalidated.

Comment: As long as things are running fine in that part of the world, I am happy. :)